# Does a trade union of YouTubers exist?

Tags: labor-economics, advertising

Would YouTubers see a sense in having a trade union?

For example, to establish policies how much the value of their contribution is.

The controversy here is, professional YouTubers make a bet for their income on the platform and have to accept its conditions, on the other hand YT has enough dominance and yet dependant on YouTubers making the bet their content will get them enough ad turnover.

Comment: Not that I know of. But on another level, a 'trade union' in spirit is a power struggle against those with too much say over smaller groups/individuals' lives. In this sense the moves towards decentralized storage, such as IPFS, could be seen as analogous endeavours.

Comment: "*how would they detect strikebreaking*" Since videos are timestamped this is not too difficult. It is hard to bust kneecaps anywhere, as it is illegal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to economics.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In 2018, the German YouTuber Jörg Sprave established [YouTubers Union](https://youtubersunion.org/) (see also [FairTube](https://fairtube.info/en/)).

In 2019, it entered into a partnership with IG Metall: [IG Metall press release](https://www.igmetall.de/presse/pressemitteilungen/ig-metall-youtubers-union-vereinbaren-zusammenarbeit), news stories by [Observer](https://observer.com/2019/10/youtube-meeting-youtubers-union-jorg-sprave/), [Bloomberg](https://www.bloomberg.com/opinion/articles/2019-08-14/german-union-ig-metall-is-backing-youtubers-fighting-google), [CNBC](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/08/06/youtubers-want-to-unionize-and-theyve-got-the-support-of-ig-metall.html).

Comment: You'll have to define what a "real" union is.

Comment: IG Metall has over 2M members.

Comment: Your question was, "Does a trade union of YouTubers exist?" If your question is in fact "Does there exist a trade union of YouTubers that meets all these criteria I keep coming up with?", then please edit your question accordingly.